# In Jenkins "Job DSL Plugin", how to specify alternate location of pom.xml in 'mavenJob'?

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I was looking at the instructions here and cannot figure out how to set a alternate `pom.xml` location of the `Root POM`, other than default.

`https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/mavenJob`

Does anyone out there know how to set that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [rootPOM](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/mavenJob-rootPOM) DSL method.

```
mavenJob('example') {
    rootPOM('sub-module/pom.xml')
}
```

Comment: Thank you .  Not sure how I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code:

```
mavenJob('JobXXX') {
  scm {
    github('Repository/Project', 'master')
    }
    goals('clean compile build')
    rootPOM('projectname/pom.xml')
}
```